# Could not find or create an instance of QuickBooks using InstanceFinder

Tags: quickbooks

I am getting the following error when running my web application to access QB company file via the sdk.

```
Could not find or create an instance of QuickBooks using InstanceFinder
```

I have tried updating quickbooks manually and I also double checked the permissions for QBXMLRP2e  DCOM object that have been set to grant permission for everyone.

I verified the filename and I have the company file open in multi user mode. I have also run the diagnostic tool which is successful.

The code used to be working fine but after a system reboot it stopped working. Also, it is mot working in our newly setup dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when an instance of QB is running in the background, foiling your attempts to start another copy. We recommend turning off the "Keep QuickBooks running" setting as [described in the FAQ for our QuickBooks reporting tool](http://www.activebooks.net/faq.html#qb-2013-bug), but hopefully the problem will go away for good as Intuit has fixed an underlying issue in [QuickBooks 2014 R6](http://support.quickbooks.intuit.com/Support/Articles/INF24723) (June 2014).

Comment: Anyone find a solution to this bug? 
My app was working just fine (and developing just nicely) - I put development on hold for a couple of weeks, come back and this problem shows up out of the blue in the log. Can't open the Quickbooks file from my app anymore (no changes to code, no changes to QB, it just randomly decides to not cooperate with the most useless error message).