# Why Quickbooks keeps crashing while syncing data via QuickBooks Web Connector when the QuickBooks Company file is not opened?

Tags: quickbooks

I am syncing data between QuickBooks and my MVC application. I am able to sync data while keeping the Company file open in the QuickBooks but not able to sync data when I close the QuickBooks window. I am getting below error:

[image]

[image]

My problem is, I can't keep open single company file as I have to sync data with multiple company files as well.

Here is the Here is the Log from **QWCLog.txt**

```
    20190228.04:23:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : updateWS() for application = 'Atria By FES - Future Energy Solutions Contracts No.1, LLLP - Customer' has STARTED
20190228.04:23:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.getUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock = FALSE
20190228.04:23:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to True
20190228.04:23:59 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session locked *********************
20190228.04:24:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : Initiated connection to the following application.
20190228.04:24:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppName: Atria By FES - Future Energy Solutions Contracts No.1, LLLP - Customer
20190228.04:24:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppUniqueName (if available): Atria By FES - Future Energy Solutions Contracts No.1, LLLP - Customer
20190228.04:24:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.instantiateWebService() : AppURL: https://atriabyfes.com:9096/WebServices/FutureEnergySolutionsContractsNoOneLLLP_Customer.asmx?wsdl
20190228.04:24:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : *** Calling serverVersion().
20190228.04:24:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_serverVersion() : Received from serverVersion() following parameter:<serverVersionRet="2.0.0.1">
20190228.04:24:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : *** Calling clientVersion() with following parameter:<productVersion="2.3.0.20">
20190228.04:24:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : Received from clientVersion() following parameter:<clientVersionRet="">
20190228.04:24:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_clientVersion() : This application agrees with the current version of QBWebConnector. Allowing update operation.
20190228.04:24:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Authenticating to application 'Atria By FES - Future Energy Solutions Contracts No.1, LLLP - Customer', username = 'Admin'
20190228.04:24:00 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : *** Calling authenticate() with following parameters:<userName="Admin"><password=<MaskedForSecurity>
20190228.04:24:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.updateWS() : Received from authenticate() following parameters:<authRet[0]="7bc6c7bb-bbb9-461f-9eae-2e45284704d8"><authRet[1]="C:\QB\QuickBooks Company File\Future Energy Solutions Contracts No.1, LLLP.QBW"><authRet[2]=""><authRet[3]="">
20190228.04:24:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setCurrentWebServiceName() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\CurrentWebServiceName has been set to Atria By FES - Future Energy Solutions Contracts No.1, LLLP - Customer
20190228.04:24:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setCurrentWebServiceSessionTicket() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\CurrentWebServiceSessionTicket has been set to 7bc6c7bb-bbb9-461f-9eae-2e45284704d8
20190228.04:24:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.CheckCFNResponse() : User authenticated.
20190228.04:24:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_authenticate() : Done.
20190228.04:24:01 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.OpenConnection() : Connecting to QuickBooks...
20190228.04:24:14 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.handleAllOtherError() : QBWC1013: Error connecting to QuickBooks. Returning error message to application.
Unexpected error. Check the "qbsdklog.txt" file for possible additional information.
20190228.04:24:14 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_connectionError() : *** Calling connectionError() with following parameters:<wcTicket="7bc6c7bb-bbb9-461f-9eae-2e45284704d8"><hresult="0x80040402"><message="Unexpected error. Check the "qbsdklog.txt" file for possible additional information.">
20190228.04:24:14 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_connectionError() : Received from connectionError() following parameters:<tryAgain="">
20190228.04:24:14 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.OpenConnection() : Connection retry #1
20190228.04:24:14 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.OpenConnection() : Received another company file from application to try again. Company file name received = <"">
20190228.04:24:14 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.OpenConnection() : Connecting to QuickBooks...
20190228.04:24:15 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.handleAllOtherError() : QBWC1013: Error connecting to QuickBooks. Returning error message to application.
Could not start QuickBooks.
20190228.04:24:15 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_connectionError() : *** Calling connectionError() with following parameters:<wcTicket="7bc6c7bb-bbb9-461f-9eae-2e45284704d8"><hresult="0x80040408"><message="Could not start QuickBooks.">
20190228.04:24:15 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_connectionError() : Received from connectionError() following parameters:<tryAgain="DONE">
20190228.04:24:15 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.OpenConnection() : Error connecting to QuickBooks. Application sent back DONE. Job ending.
20190228.04:24:15 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20190228.04:24:15 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20190228.04:24:15 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.DoUpdateSelected() : Update completed with errors. See log (QWClog.txt) for details.
```

And here is the log from qbsdklog.txt

```
20190228.042800 I   6956    RequestProcessor    ========= Started Connection =========
20190228.042800 I   6956    RequestProcessor    Request Processor, QBXMLRP2 v13.0
20190228.042800 I   6956    RequestProcessor    Connection opened by app named 'Atria By FES - Future Energy Solutions Contracts No.1, LLLP - Customer'
20190228.042800 I   6956    CertVerifier    The Authenticode signature validated OK.
20190228.042800 I   6956    RequestProcessor    OS: Microsoft Standard Edition (build 9200), 64-bit
20190228.042800 I   6956    RequestProcessor    Current Process Integrity Level : 2000
20190228.042803 I   6956    RequestProcessor    Quickbooks is not running currently
20190228.042803 I   6956    RequestProcessor    Launch a new instance of Quickbooks
20190228.042805 I   6956    RequestProcessor    Getting the IUnknown COM instance of QB
20190228.042805 I   6956    RequestProcessor    Opening the file in the DoNotCare mode.
20190228.042807 E   6956    RequestProcessor    Begin Session error = 800706be

20190228.042808 I   6956    RequestProcessor    ========= Started Connection =========
20190228.042808 I   6956    RequestProcessor    Request Processor, QBXMLRP2 v13.0
20190228.042808 I   6956    RequestProcessor    Connection opened by app named 'Atria By FES - Future Energy Solutions Contracts No.1, LLLP - Customer'
20190228.042808 I   6956    CertVerifier    The Authenticode signature validated OK.
20190228.042808 I   6956    RequestProcessor    OS: Microsoft Standard Edition (build 9200), 64-bit
20190228.042808 I   6956    RequestProcessor    Current Process Integrity Level : 2000
20190228.042808 E   6956    RequestProcessor    QuickBooks is not running and the data file name is not provided. Cannot continue.
20190228.042808 E   6956    RequestProcessor    Could not find or create an instance of QuickBooks using InstanceFinder hr = 80040416
20190228.042829 I   6956    RequestProcessor    "CloseConnection" has not been called.
20190228.042853 I   6956    RequestProcessor    "CloseConnection" has not been called.
```

Please help!

FYI: It was working earlier, but it suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Log its show **"Could not find or create an instance of QuickBooks".**

Here are things to look at if you are getting a "Could not start QuickBooks" error message.

- Make sure your app is built for Target x86 only.
- Make sure the Keep QuickBooks running is Un-checked in the General
  Preferences.
- Make sure QuickBooks and your application are running at the same
  user level.
- They both need to be running as a normal user or both running as
  administrator, but not mixed.
- If you are running in Visual Studio and trying to debug, you are
  probably running in a mixed permission mode. VS runs as
  administrator, so you will need to start QuickBooks using the Run As
  Administrator option.
- Make sure the Path and Filename are correct.
- QuickBooks and QBXML SDK applications are NOT designed to run as a
  service. They have to run in the context of a user.

reference:

https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/article/Troubleshooting-Could-not-start-QuickBooks

[Could not find or create an instance of QuickBooks using InstanceFinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20260646/could-not-find-or-create-an-instance-of-quickbooks-using-instancefinder)